# Remove Wordpress "Comments are closed" message from posts without comments, possible?

Tags: wordpress, comments, action, hook

The Wordpress `comment_form_comments_closed` hook fires when comments are closed, even if they were never open for a post and, consequently, the "Comments are closed" message will show up after every post where comments have been disabled. Is there a way to remove the message if comments were never enabled for a post? It should be possible to have a post without both comments and a comment form not to show this message. A post containing comments which have been closed should, on the other hand, show the message.

```
function my_comments_closed() {
        if ( ! is_page() AND post_type_supports( get_post_type(), 'comments' ) ) : ?>
            <p class="nocomments"><?php _e( 'Comments are closed', 'mytheme' ); ?></p>
        <?php endif;
    }
    add_action( 'comment_form_comments_closed', 'my_comments_closed' );
```

Comment: Just check to see how many comments the post has before you determine if the message should be displayed.

Comment: Thanks you got me thinking in the right direction and I found the simple solution: just replace second line of code with `if ( have_comments() ) : ?>`