# Remove comments are closed from WP Headway theme

Tags: php, wordpress

I've read the posts on this page: [Remove Wordpress "Comments are closed" message from posts without comments, possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12534264/remove-wordpress-comments-are-closed-message-from-posts-without-comments-poss)

but am still unsure how to implement exactly the same function on my website. ie. If there are no comments or comments weren't enabled, I don't want "comments are closed..." etc to appear.

I use the theme Headway, v 2.0.13.
Can anyone explain how I do this? I presume I alter the code in comments.php, but need exact instructions as to what needs removing, amending or adding.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have not seem the comments.php template file but this is taken from another.

```
<?php else : // comments are closed ?>
    <!-- If comments are closed. -->
    <p class="nocomments">Comments are closed.</p>

<?php endif; ?>
```

Just remove this part

```
         <p class="nocomments">Comments are closed.</p>
```

I would guess that it is around line 50 in comments.php

Comment: In your code editor of choice find in the document (comments.php) 
(ctrl + f) "Comments are closed". Hopefully this string will be on an entire line of it's in a <p> tag, simple delete the entire line if this is the case.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use [Hide Comments are Closed](https://wordpress.org/plugins/hide-comments-are-closed-text/) plugin. There is no setting of this plugin. Just install and text will hide automatically.